# ASP for faster development

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I've developed medium/big Java web apps last 5 years and i want to take a look of some platform/tool for small size web development.
I have ASP in mind, and sometimes i've heard   that ASP .net platform is better than Java EE for faster development of small/medium size web apps. 
Is this true?
can anyone argue this?

Comment: I think the best platform for faster development is the one you have the most experience with

Comment: The choice of platform won't make or break your app. I'd say the main advantage of the .NET stack is that it caught on to the trend of developer convenience earlier than Java EE; so a problem with Javaland is more that many developers / organisations are stuck on doing things the old hard way, rather than that RAD options don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on Java/Java EE and .NET 3.5. I have noticed that .NET is somewhat faster to code and build because of Visual Studio. But if you can write build scripts and if you are sure about the server to use[JBOSS, Tomcat etc], Java EE can look pretty simple.
To conclude, I would just go with .NET since I know I can use only IIS, I just have to right click, build and deploy and I dont need to learn ANT, UNIX scripts and I dont have to research  on which server to use.

Answer (score 3):

Many view ASP.NET and Microsoft technology in general to be easier to learn -- hence easier to find employee to work on the project. In terms of performance it's arguable. You mostly end up with never-ending debate. I personally don't see why one is significantly more superior than the other

The general wisdom of comparing Java vs .NET is: Java is a single language (single spec) but multiple vendors (for example you have JBoss, Websphere, Weblogic etc all implementing Java EE spec), while microsoft is multiple language but single vendor (you can code ASP + VB or C#)